# React Native - RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY is nil in view init method

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, react-native-native-ui-component

I am trying to create a Native UI component on my RN project on iOS.
I pass a props `uri` to my Native component. But when I try to use it in the `init` method of my view, it is `nil`.

```
// myNativeComponentManager.m

@implementation myNativeComponentManager

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(uri, NSString *);

- (UIView *)view
{
    return [[myNativeComponentView alloc] init];
}

@end

// myNativeComponentView.m

@implementation myNativeComponentView

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];

// self.uri is nil here
    NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.uri];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

    self.imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    self.imgView.image = image;
    self.imgView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    self.imgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [self addSubview:self.imgView];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap =
    [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(onTap:)];
    [self.imgView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

    return self;
}

- (void)onTap:(id)sender {
// self.uri is not nil here
    NSLog(self.uri);
}
 @end
```

`uri` is `nil` in the `init` but not in the `onTap` method so it makes me think we can't use property in the init method? In that case, how do I initialise my image with this uri? Is there a way to know the view did initialized? I thought about creating a method to set my image and calling it on the JS part in `componentDidMount` but it feels wrong.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

props passed from react native cannot be fetch in init method of native UIView.
You should handle it in property setter method.

```
// react native x.js
export default class EmailSSO extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var credential = {
            username: "abc",
            password: "xyz",
        };
        return (
            <EmailView credential={credential} style={{ flex: 1 }} />
        );
    }
}

// native XXXView.m
- (void)setCredential:(Credential *)credential
{
  _credential = credential;
  NSLog(@"Username is %@", credential.username);
}
```